# Каким методом лучше отправить следующий POST запрос на C#? Если известен CURL

Tags: c#, curl

```
$ curl -D- -XPUT -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
    -H"X-Api-Key: $APIKEY" \
    --data-binary @- \
    https://dns.api.gandi.net/api/v5/zones/93cc9312-a214-408b-a75b-9d4172984746/records \
    << EOF
www IN A 192.168.0.1
    IN A 192.168.0.2
@   IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
EOF
```

Через CURL отправляет запрос следующим образом. 
Как отправить то же самое средствами NET?

Comment: вы же уже задавали этот вопрос. Зачем его снова задавать? Ну, и, спрошу то же, что и там - вы сами что то пробовали? Как то пытались решить проблему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/5045688